# Omnidirectional camera (fisheye/wide angle) model support

Tags: ros, model, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

looking at the [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo Message](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html) and/or at the [camera_calibration_parsers](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers) it seems that ROS supports only the Pinhole model for cameras (out of the box).

Is there some ***known way*** we could use the [Scaramuzza model](https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox) model for omnidirectional cameras?

Currently working under Indigo.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277153/omnidirectional-camera-(fisheye/wide-angle)-model-support/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I implemented some tooling for reading ocamlib calibration files  and generating rectified images from fisheye cams as part of our DRC participation here: [vigir_wide_angle_image_proc](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_wide_angle_image_proc). The [rectify](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_wide_angle_image_proc/blob/master/vigir_wide_angle_image_proc/src/nodelets/rectify.cpp)  nodelet is also capable of simulating a pinhole camera with two (yaw, pitch) joints and generating appropriate camera_info and joint_states.

That being said, nowadays I'd recommend using the excellent [kalibr](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr) calibration toolbox which can jointly calibrate multiple cameras with good ROS integration.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-12-04**:
Thanks for the code Stefan! I'll check it out ;)